# $_POST[] variable returning empty on form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a simple `PHP` form containing two (2) textboxes a dropdownlist and finally a SUBMIT button. In this form, before hitting the Submit button, the user has to select an item from the dropdown list. Upon selection of an item from the dropdown list, it's `onchange` event fires and populates the other 2 textboxes with some data fetched from the database.

The code to fetch data:

```
var wd_pid = document.getElementById("ddlUnder").value;
var dataString = 'wdpid='+ wd_pid;
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ldd_pop_wd_pdata.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                        var v1= result.substring(0,result.indexOf('='));
                        var v2= result.substring(result.indexOf('=')+1);
                               $("#txtMLI").val(v1);
                               $("#txtMLIURL").val(v2);
                      }
         });
```

The above code works perfectly, populating the two textboxes with correct data. This forms 'action' attribute points to an another php page containing logic to save form data into the database. My problem begins in the next page. After form submit, in the next php page, the post variables `$_POST['txtMLI'] & $_POST['txtMLIURL']` are empty.Why is it so?? Please advise what's going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to send data in this manner             data: {dataString:dataString}

Comment: Show the form as well.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: `POST` variables are not sessions, they will only exist in the context of the page they where loaded on. If you want to keep a variable stored through many pages you will want to use `SESSIONS`. Also values are stored based on `name` attributes and not `id`'s.

Comment: Are you sure the data is comming into the textboxes?. I see you are doing a POST with ajax using a querystring instead of a GET to fetch it. 
Debug this call on the console, and then if the data is there, then post the code for the submit action you do afterwards. Check this for reference on how to your DDL ajax call: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384647/ajax-php-function-onchange-select-box

Answer (score 0):

The `data` part of your AJAX call is not properly formatted. It is supposed to be formatted in JSON as follows.

```
{ wdpid: wd_pid }
```

And not

```
"wdpid=" + wd_pid
```

Comment: It can accept strings, if JSON was given it would need to be parsed.