# How to show names in a <select> but send the id to Ajax

Tags: php

I'm displaying the names of groups in a drop down list, and the user will select one option. I want to send to ajax the id of this group, not the name.
The following HTML will send the name but not the group_id. Any help ?

```
<select class="form-control" style="width:150px" name="grps" id="grps">
@foreach ($j_grp as $j_grps)
<option>{{ $j_grps->name }}</option>
@endforeach
 </select>
```

Comment: The above doesn't _send_ anything.  You should show your Javascript code.  But most likely you'll need to assign the id to the option value attribute.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384647/ajax-php-function-onchange-select-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384647/ajax-php-function-onchange-select-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need define `VALUE` on select option.

```
<select class="form-control" style="width:150px" name="grps" id="grps">
@foreach ($j_grp as $j_grps)
  <option value="{{ $j_grps->id }}">{{ $j_grps->name }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```