# Change direct input select in the database php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem, I am developing a system and I need an order status change to take place, however this change has to be done with select and option and as soon as the person sets the new status of the order she does an update right in my database, how can I do this? do i have to use javascript?

my code:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <select class="form-control" name="select">
                        <option>Awaiting</option>
                        <option>In analysis</option>
                        <option>Payment declined</option>
                        <option>Payment confirmed</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Remembering that I have all the saving logic, I just don't know how to save the data without a submit button, just changing the select options.

Comment: yes you need to fire off an ajax request which is done with js using a change event on the select, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384647/ajax-php-function-onchange-select-box

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AJAX PHP function onchange select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384647/ajax-php-function-onchange-select-box)